# How to find the difference and product of two correlated normally distributed random variables.

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution

If $X \sim N(10,3)$ and $Y \sim N(15,8)$ and if X and Y are correlated with a correlation coefficient of 0.6. What is the probability distribution of

1. X - Y
2. 3X
3. 4X + 5Y

For the sum of X and Y, I understand that $\sigma_{X+Y}=\sqrt[]{\sigma_{X}^2+\sigma_{Y}^2+2\rho\cdot \sigma_{X} \cdot\sigma_{Y}}$ applies. But when I simply replace the + signs with - signs, the inside of the square root becomes negative...

So I'm ultimately looking for some $ N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ for the different problems.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Note that: $X-Y=X+(-Y)$.

Comment: Does this mean $\sigma_{Y)^2$ and $\sigma_{Y}$ become negative? That would still yield a negative square root. I think I don't understand the implications of your comment.

Comment: Actually, since $var(-Y)=(-1)^2 var(Y)= var(Y)$, the formula above in the case of a minus just becomes $\sigma_{X-Y}=\sqrt{\sigma^2_X+\sigma^2_Y-2 \rho \sigma_X \sigma_Y}$.

Comment: Thanks for opening my eyes! So I have 8.1928 for the first problem.

For the second, I guess, the correlation doesn't matter because we are only multiplying one of the variables by a constant, so its variance should be multiplied by the square of the constant, to give us 27.

For the third problem, do we combine the rule for addition ($\sigma_{X+Y}=\sqrt[]{\sigma_{X}^2+\sigma_{Y}^2+2\rho\cdot \sigma_{X} \cdot\sigma_{Y}}$) with that of multiplication (i.e. multiplying the variance by the square of the constants)?